# Bootstrap Elements inactive in mobile

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of elements on my page that are visible to a certain breakpoint, but when the dimensions are within say a Tablet or Mobile size I want to be able to display the content as Modals.

Ok, so I have managed to only show the buttons needed for the modal on smaller screens, but say I expand my screen, the content has residual elements from the modal functionality, such as fade and modal.

Plus when you close a modal you get the element: display: none, which is a problem, and if I also decrease again the fade effect is still there.

Is there anyway of enabling the modal effect when within certain breakpoints?

Comment: Certainly nothing built into Bootstrap, no. Unless you're okay with lots of duplicated markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into responsive utilities and utilise the `.visible-xs` or `.hidden-xs` in your class tags of the modal. See here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Problem is I don't want to hide the content, I want to disable the functionality at wider viewports.

Comment: So you want to disable the model but keep the content? The modal has a button to launch, yes? Show me your code so I can get a clear example.

Comment: re-think your structure. You're using additional code. What you're looking to do is not built into bootstrap. To disable content hide the content in viewports or in this case your modal not the button that activates it.

Comment: Yes but the content in my modal, I am displaying on the page in wider viewports.  So when I reduce my viewport, that content then becomes accessible only via a button that opens it up in a modal.

Comment: If you're using content inside a modal, then duplicate the content in a div outside and separate from the modal. Use `visible-xs` or whatever hide/show responsive-utilities you need in each viewport to hide and show that particular div. e.g: show in smaller view ports, hide in larger viewports.

Comment: Was trying to avoid that.  Perhaps I could use jQuery to remove classes at certain breakpoints.

Comment: I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  Perhaps if I uploaded it to a url someone could help.

Comment: Here is a URL to check. http://uniform.pixelsandcode.co.uk/arch-viz-image-library.html